# Calculate the index number of a value - bitwise sort of

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

I want to provide user visibility to subscription pages using bitwise operators . As like if user's permission for page is 60 then he will only able to see those subscription  pages which visibility is set on 2,3,4,5 (eg. 2^2 =4,2^3=8,2^4=16,2^5=32 so 32+16+4+2 =60 so he is allowed to view pages which permission id =2,3,4,5)

```
   public function permission($perm)
   {
     $this->permission = ~$perm & $this->permission;
   }
```

I used this code but it is useless
I need help and suggesations.......Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is tagged [tag:mysql], but you may wish to look into its [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html) datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a permission:

```
$this->permission |= $perm;
```

Checking if a permission is set:

```
$is_permitted = (bool)($this->permission & $perm);
```

Checking which permissions are set:

```
for ($permissions = array(), $i = ceil(log($this->permission, 2) + 0.1) /* floating point imprecision */; $i >= 0; $i--)
    if ($this->permission & (1 << $i))
        $permissions[] = $i;
```

Comment: this is how you use bitwise operators; why should you need another way?

Comment: @user2579137 don't know what I should answer?

Comment: Ok, let me explain, there is a number which says 36, so permission id accessible by 36 is 2,5 because 2^2 = 4, 2^5 = 32, 32+4 = 36... What you showed is a boolean check.. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @user2579137 you mean you want all the permissions set return as an array?

Comment: Yes... that's right... I just edited the question. Hope it is clear now... I know it is bit algorithmic and logical... I tried various combinations... Any ideas?

Comment: I will try and come back, brb 5 mins.

Comment: I wish I could give you 100 points. Thank you so much. I love u :-*

Comment: What is << operator called?

Comment: @404NotFound (left) bitshift

Comment: You are so eleet! GodCoder! :)